# Placing images over eachother with position:absolute without using top

Tags: html, css

I want to place my images over one another and right below it I want to make show an overview of the tumbnails.

The only way I succeeded in placing the images over eachother is by using position:absolute and top, left to 0px.

But the images are uploaded to the server so they will have variable height, so I cannot use top: xx px; on them.

Can I solve this with css only? I tried to make the problem clear here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wWY5H/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this with CSS only is having an `position: absolute` container with a fixed width, and to place all images in there the normal way. They will stack up underneath each other.

If that is not an option and the *images* need to be `position: absolute`, you will need the help of server side scripting or jQuery to determine the image heights.

Comment: the best way for me was taking the height of the largest image and set that as the height of the div, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` in your CSS, that should do the trick. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: He means underneath each other I think

Comment: @pekka Not really sure, he says 'over on another', that could be done by z-index. But your'e right; he could also mean just underneath. Maybe the OPS can give the final answer?

Answer (score 0):

Without having a static height on the container (`#top` in your case), I don't see how it can be solved.
What you could do, is get the height of the `<img>` tags with a javascript, and set the `#top` to use that height.

I've updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dekket/wWY5H/6/

So in short, I don't see a way of doing this with only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If pictures are same size you can use `margin-left:-100%` on pictures n>0.